# hamcrest - how to negate hasXPath to test document does not contain certain child node?

Tags: unit-testing, hamcrest

I want to test that some XML document does **not** contain certain XPath, how should I assert that in unit test using Hamcrest matcher?

For example I want to assert the document has no `foo/bar` under `pos`:

```
    assertThat(document, Matchers.hasXPath(
            "/svc_result/slia/pos/foo/bar)]")  # negate here
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should use XPath negate, as Hamcrest does not support matcher negation:

```
    assertThat(document, Matchers.hasXPath(
            "/svc_result/slia/pos[not(foo/bar)]")
    );
```

`parent[not(xxx)]` means "this XPath parent does not contain a child node xxx".

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert;
import org.hamcrest.core.IsNot;
import org.xmlunit.matchers.HasXPathMatcher;
// ...
MatcherAssert.assertThat(document, IsNot.not(HasXPathMatcher.hasXPath("/svc_result/slia/pos/foo/bar)]")));
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, as this is later so I mark myself as accepted answer; and I notice you have 2 not so it's like double negate. Also I suggest using Markdown code formatting to make it more readable.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).